# How to use already running SafariDriver in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, capybara, safaridriver

In order to avoid problem that I've described in separate question: [Unable to run tests against Safari 11 remotely (ssh, CI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262318/unable-to-run-tests-against-safari-11-remotely-ssh-ci)
I'm trying to do following scenario:

1. Run SafariDriver manually using command: 
   `/usr/bin/safaridriver -p 7050`
2. Run Capybara/RSpec tests which will attach to already running SafariDriver instead of trying to initiate new one on new port.

Is there any way to achieve this using either Capybara or underneath Selenium?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't You just run Safaridriver on given port and create RemoteWebDriver in Capybara and connect to it via "http://localhost:7050" ?

Comment: Posted a answer on your other thread, see if it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

Comment: SafariDriver only binds to the internal ip address (127.0.0.1 / ::1) so a remote running Selenium won't be able to connect to it without you setting up some sort of tunnel.