# safaridriver not working over ssh

Tags: selenium, jenkins, macos-high-sierra, safaridriver

I have Jenkins working with OS X slave nodes using selenium over ssh.

I've successfully run the command below to ensure that it is configured correctly.

```
/usr/bin/safaridriver --enable
```

When I run a build, I can see the tests starting to run and safaridriver runs, but immediately exits with an error code. At this stage the tests hang.

If I manually run safaridriver with the exact same commandline, then the tests start.

In essense, `/usr/bin/safaridriver` **errors out when run over ssh**, but doesn't if it is run locally. The same is true no matter what user you run it as.

I'm using `High Sierra`, `Safari 11.1.2` and `Selenium 3.14`.

Anyone run into this problem?

Comment: I am seeing similar error when selenium is launched in Nodejs program that is started using pm2. SafariDriver says that it is not configured

Answer (score 0):

You can use Automator to create an app to start safaridriver, like this:
[Unable to run tests against Safari 11 remotely (ssh, CI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262318/unable-to-run-tests-against-safari-11-remotely-ssh-ci)